# Why are the internals of NES Gamepaks so small compared to the case?

Tags: nintendo, nes, chip, game-cartridge

As you probably know, in the technology world, smaller is generally considered to be better. Companies compete to make the most portable phone, or the smallest laptop, but apparently Nintendo didn't get the memo on this back in the '80s, because if you take a look inside an NES cartridge you may notice they were opting for the exact opposite:

[image]

In other words, the case is massive compared to the internals.

Why would they do this? Why would anyone do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Those chips are two 32-pin 0.6-inch wide chips, and a 16-pin 0.3-wide chip, on 0.1-inch pitch, which was the normal size then.  What makes you say they are small?

Comment: look at the size of the case

Comment: Do you mean the case is big?

Comment: Are we looking at the same image? The image linked shows no 'chips', but rather the underside of a printed circuit board. Showing only traces and the card edge connector, with the only electronic component visible being an electrolytic capacitor on the top right.

Comment: The case is big enough to hold components that could be larger than the example shown. Also, while electronic components are made smaller over time, human hands have not shown a similar trend.

Comment: http://images.nintendolife.com/news/2012/08/rare_final_fantasy_ii_nes_cartridge_hits_ebay/large.jpg

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Under the hood, the NES was almost identical to the Famicom, its Japanese counterpart released in 1983:

[image: Famicom]
<sup>[image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nintendo-Famicom-Console-Set-FL.png)</sup>

The Famicom console itself was much smaller that the NES, and it had a traditional top-loading cartridge slot instead of the NES's notoriously unreliable front-loader.  It's cartridges were also more reasonably sized:

[image: Famicom with cartridge]

[image: Inside of cartridge]

<sup>[Image source](https://www.wired.com/2010/09/nintendo-famicom-teardown/)</sup>

At the time the NES was released in the United States, [the North American video game market had just crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_crash_of_1983).  Consumers were unwilling to buy video game systems, and retailers were unwilling to sell them.  The Nintendo Entertainment System made quite a few unusual design decisions in an effort to market the NES as an "entertainment system" rather than a video game console.  According to the Wikipedia article [History of the Nintendo Entertainment System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Nintendo_Entertainment_System#Redesign_as_the_Nintendo_Entertainment_System_(1985)):

> Nintendo purposefully designed the system so as not to resemble a video game console, and would avoid terms associated with game consoles, using the term "Pak" for cartridge, or "Control Deck" instead of "console". Renamed the "Nintendo Entertainment System" (NES), the new version lacked most of the upscale features added in the AVS, but retained many of its design elements, such as the grey color scheme and boxy design. In avoidance of an obvious video game connotation, NES replaced the top-loading cartridge slot of the Famicom with a front-loading chamber for software cartridges that place the inserted cartridge out of view. The revised design includes design flaws which have the side-effect of making the NES more prone to breakdown. The loading mechanism became notorious for slowly failing. The Famicom's pair of hard-wired controllers was replaced with two custom 7-pin sockets for detachable controllers.

Nintendo knew they couldn't sell a video game system, so they made something that looked futuristic and *not like a video game system.*  The design decision of inserting a large cartridge into a slot on the front of the system [was an effort to resemble something like a VCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Entertainment_System#Design_flaws) rather than a game console.

Answer (score 10):

The mechanical aspects of the NES require that all NES Gamepaks be about the same size.  NES could not predict with certainty everything that game designers might want to include in a Gamepak, and were more interested in ensuring that the cartridges could handle the worst-case need than in making them as small as possible.

Making the cartridges larger would also cater toward an attitude that increased size correlates with more sophistication, and made it easier for people to acquire an impressive-looking collections of games.

Which looks more impressive: a stack of 10 NES cartridges, or a stack of 20 Nintendo DS cartridges?

Comment: This sounds silly but I believe it to be accurate.  I've read that the Apple 2c sold less than the 2e because the newer, more powerful, and more compact computer (the 2c) was widely judged to be a cheaper, junkier, and less capable machine because of its smaller size.  So making the cartridges larger was very likely an attempt, and a successful one at that, to do exactly what the latter part of this answer is describing.  (Not meaning to discredit the first part of this answer, which I also agree to be a valid reason.)

Comment: @TOOGAM I was still quite young when our family got a IIc, and for many, many years, I thought it _was_ the cheaper, weaker version of the IIe.  I never could understand how all the games that had special requirements always seemed to work (at least 48k ram, etc)

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach: It's harder to use an Apple //c with software downloaded from the Internet than either an Apple ][+ or an Apple //e, but not for the reason anyone would have expected at the time: the Apple //c lacks the cassette audio input port that the earlier machines had, which turns out to be surprisingly useful for receiving data from a mobile phone, tablet, or other such device.

Comment: For the North American market, wouldn't the larger size have also made them (slightly) more difficult to shoplift?  The NES pak winds up being about the size of a YA novel, which I don't think is a coincidence either.  Lastly, I suspect the resulting taller boxes would have been seen as more attractive on video game rental shop shelves.